# How to loop through an array in angular controller and display one item at a time

Tags: angularjs

I would love to loop through the following array in my controller,

```
var array = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];
```

Then display an item at a time in my view using angular $interval.

When it gets to the last item, it should start again from item 1. Only one item should be displayed at a time.

Please don't judge, sounds easy but this is my 2nd week or so with angularjs.

Comment: It's a basic carousel - just have to think through it. You need an `activeItem` to denote which item is currently being displayed - and each interval, check the index of the active item and go to the next. If you're at the last index, start at the beginning.

Comment: any example for a start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you rotate text values in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570207/how-do-you-rotate-text-values-in-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated answer according to @Nicholas Robinson and @4castle suggestion on the comments:

```js
angular
    .module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope, $interval) {
        $scope.array = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'];

        $scope.showedItem = 0;

        $interval(function() {
            $scope.showedItem = ++$scope.showedItem % $scope.array.length;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <!-- <p ng-repeat="item in array" ng-show="showedItem === $index">{{item}}</p> -->
    <!-- Improvements without the need of ng-repeat and ng-show -->
    <p>{{ array[showedItem] }}</p>
</div>
```

**Updated answer** according to @Nicholas Robinson and @4castle suggestion on the comments.

Comment: Instead of `$scope.showedItem++; if ($scope.showedItem > $scope.array.length){$scope.showedItem = 0;}` you can just use `$scope.showedItem = ++$scope.showedItem % $scope.array.length` - Works the same

Comment: You don't need `ng-repeat` or `ng-show`. Just bind to `{{ array[showedItem] }}`